# linux diff tool output with relative prefix

Tags: linux, diff

The *diff* output with file path is too long. I will like to remove the path for readable with *diff* built-in parameter/option without via *shell script* ?

```
$ diff -u /share/a/b/c/d /share/1/2/3/4/             <== path is too long
diff -u /share/a/b/c/d/dirsave /share/1/2/3/4/dirsave
--- /share/a/b/c/d/dirsave      2017-08-11 16:21:50.100547799 +0800
+++ /share/1/2/3/4/dirsave      2017-08-11 16:22:21.612546684 +0800
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 pushd /share/qca6174/qca6174a-5-pci/QCA6174A-5-PCI/fixce/AIO/rootfs-ra-r105.build/lib/firmware
 pushd /share/qca6174/qca6174a-5-pci/QCA6174A-5-PCI
+libc
```

However, The path is too long for me.
I want to get shortly path like as

```
diff -u dirsave dirsave                                <== enhance shortly path
--- dirsave     2017-08-11 16:21:50.100547799 +0800
+++ dirsave     2017-08-11 16:22:21.612546684 +0800
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 pushd /share/qca6174/qca6174a-5-pci/QCA6174A-5-PCI/fixce/AIO/rootfs-ra-r105.build/lib/firmware
 pushd /share/qca6174/qca6174a-5-pci/QCA6174A-5-PCI
+libc
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question because **[`diff` utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) does not exist in Linux** (the kernel). It exists in **GNU**, and it exists in **Unix**, because those are operating systems. Linux is a kernel, usually packaged with GNU and distributed as [GNU/Linux](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-linux-faq.en.html#why).

With this being said, if you are using GNU `diff` (from GNU `diffutils`), then you can use the [`--label LABEL` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Alternate-Names) (twice) to specify the alternate names you wish to see printed in place of the file names.

In your example:

```
$ diff -u --label file1 --label file2 /share/a/b/c/d /share/1/2/3/4/             
--- file1
+++ file2
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 pushd /share/qca6174/qca6174a-5-pci/QCA6174A-5-PCI/fixce/AIO/rootfs-ra-r105.build/lib/firmware
 pushd /share/qca6174/qca6174a-5-pci/QCA6174A-5-PCI
+libc
```

If you're stuck with [POSIX `diff`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html), then I'd say your best option is to rewrite that header with `sed` or `awk`.